# Is there a way to refresh symbolic links in Android sdcard programmatically

Tags: android, linux, shell, symlink, android-external-storage

I am practicing to create a system app and testing using a rooted device. The application copies files(images,music and video) from a zip file to a the directory `/data/media/0/SampleFolder`. But after the files are copied, they are not recognized or can not be opened when viewed using `ES File Explorer File Manager`.

When I view via adb shell and enter the command `ls -l /sdcard/SampleFolder/`, the files are then recognized and they can be opened after entering said command. If not mistaken, the paths data/media and sdcard have symbolic links.

Does this mean that there is a sync problem between `/data/media` and `/sdcard/` and if yes, is there a way to refresh it programmatically?

Note: The following have been tried but have not been successful:

- Rebooting the device
- entering `ls -l` command programmatically
- called MediaScannerConnection.scanfile for each file in the `/sdcard/SampleFolder` directory
- broadcasting `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory
- broadcast `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` for each file in the `/sdcard/SampleFolder` directory

Comment: Google a bit. This isn't new.

Comment: @323go yeah, I read that changes in data/media do not emulate in /sdcard/ but is there a way to programmatically emulate the folder's contents to /sdcard ? and if I'am still missing any concept, any advise would be of great help